Session management problem in Next JS where the session is not being available in a sub-domain
I am trying to solve a problem where I have a website, and upon logging in or using sign-up, a session is created in the root domain (For example: localhost:3000) where my application is running. Now, ideally my website is tenants based so for each tenant, there is a different subdomain to be used with the root domain (For example: app.localhost:3000). Now, the session is being created perfectly in the root domain but upon logging in, when I redirect to the sub-domain, the session returns empty there. I have tried everything, I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Here is the "/api/auth[...nextauth]/route.ts" file which is creating the said session using CredentialsProvider.
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma"
import { compare } from "bcrypt"

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Custom",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log("Attempting to authorize user:", credentials?.email)

        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          console.log("Missing email or password")
          return null
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email }
        })

        if (!user) {
          console.log("User not found")
          return null
        }

        if (!user.passwordHash) {
          console.log("User has no password hash")
          return null
        }

        const isPasswordValid = await compare(credentials.password, user.passwordHash)

        if (!isPasswordValid) {
          if (credentials.password === user.passwordHash) {
            console.log("User authorized successfully")
            return {
              id: user.id.toString(),
              email: user.email,
              name: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
            }
          }
          console.log("Invalid password")
          return null
        }

        console.log("User authorized successfully")
        return {
          id: user.id.toString(),
          email: user.email,
          name: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60,
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60, // 1 hour in seconds
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: {
      token: { id: string },
      user: { id: string }
    }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }: {
      session: any,
      token: { id: string }
    }) {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id
      }
      return session
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in",
    newUser: "/sign-up"
  },
  debug: true, // Enable debug messages in the console
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: false,
        domain: '.localhost'
      }
    }
  },
  
  // Simplified CORS configuration for localhost
  cors: {
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'http://app.localhost:3000',
      'http://app1.localhost:3000',
      'http://app2.localhost:3000',
      'http://farhan-dev.localhost:3000'
    ],
    credentials: true,
  }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

Please let me know if you guys need anything else at all from my project. I'll gladly provide it to you to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
